# Changing git system gitconfig location on linux

Tags: git, git-config

I want to relocate $PREFIX/etc/gitconfig to some other location but without recompiling git.

How I can do that?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try to create a symbolic link inside `$PREFIX/etc/` named `gitconfig` pointing to the location you need?

Comment: I wanted to avoid this "trick". It would've been much easier with the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, since that value is baked into the binary.  You can either recompile to change the value, or you can set `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` to avoid reading the existing one.

This is the way most FLOSS programs that use prefix-based paths work.

Comment: I don't mind not reading the original one but I still need a system-wide config file.

Comment: If you need a separate one, then you need to recompile.  That's just the way it is.  You could also include yours with an include directive in `/etc/gitconfig` (see `git-config(1)`).